# Joining Words in String In-Place

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have a list of strings in which I wanted to join two words by making new "list of string". However after running some codes its no where near the result as per my assumption.

text = ['A','123','BCR','EF','RTY','B','123','VCR','EF','B','123','RRR','EF','RTY']

code

```
for k in range(0,len(text)):
        a = [i for i,x in enumerate(text) if x == "EF"]
        b = [i for i,x in enumerate(text) if x == "RTY"]
        for l in range(0,len(a)):
            for m in range(0,len(b)):
                if a[l] == b[m] - 1 :
                    text[a[l]] = text[a[l]]+text[b[m]]
```

As you can see "EF" is always before "RTY" (till now) but taking safe side I am deducting the index or position. Any clue.

Answer has been updated in the question.

Comment: Python strings are immutable. So you can't modify them in-place.

Comment: What's the expected output? what should be `text`'s contents at the end? And @HunterMcMillen is right, you can't mutate a string in-place, that's not possible in Python

Comment: To be clear, `text` is not a string, it's a list of strings. Are you trying to modify a string? Or a list of strings?

Comment: Thanks for the important information about the "immutability" of list of "strings". So is it possible to create a new "list of strings".

Comment: @LonelySoul what is your expected output?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary a new list with elements like text = ['A','123','BCR','EFRTY']

Comment: What should happen to the original RTY? If you change the last line to `text[a[l]]+=text[b[m]]`, you'll get `['A', '123', 'BCR', 'EFRTY', 'RTY', 'B', '123', 'VCR', 'EF', 'B', '123', 'RRR', 'EFRTY', 'RTY']`. Not an efficient way to do it, but you get there.

Comment: @tdelaney true. I am planning to eliminate it in the separate step. any good suggestion to do it one very easy step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable in python, you should assign back the result of concatenation to a variable:

```
text[a[l]] = text[a[l]]+text[b[m]]
```

**Output:**

```
['A', '123', 'BCR', 'EFRTY', 'RTY', 'B', '123', 'VCR', 'EF', 'B', '123', 'RRR', 'EFRTY', 'RTY']
```

Comment: Thanks Ashwini. Was very close and you really guided me.

Answer (score 2):

To join all adjacent `'EF'`, `'RTY'` non-overlapping pairs in a list:

```
L = ['A','123','BCR','EF','RTY','B','123','VCR','EF','B','123','RRR','EF','RTY']

result = []
pairs = iter(zip(L, L[1:]+['']))
for a, b in pairs:
    if a == 'EF' and b == 'RTY': # found adjacent
       a += b # join
       next(pairs, None) # skip the next a ('RTY')
    result.append(a)
L[:] = result # modify inplace
# -> ['A','123','BCR','EFRTY','B','123','VCR','EF','B','123','RRR','EFRTY']
```

To support more than two words:

```
seq = ["EF", "RTY", "B"]
pos = i = 0
while i < len(L):
    if L[i:i+len(seq)] == seq:
        L[pos] = "".join(seq)
        i += len(seq)
    else:
        L[pos] = L[i]
        i += 1
    pos += 1     
del L[pos:]
```

Comment: Thats a really interesting solution @J.F.Sebastian. However If I want to add one more word then how will you change the code

Comment: @LonelySoul: I've added the code that supports more than two words.

Comment: If you have more than 1 sequence then might want to reset pos as "pos = i = 0" . Might be helpful for someone .